# Make sound louder in ogg video

Tags: linux, video

I have recorded screencast video with GtkRecordMyDesktop, in ogg format. Microphone was wrongly placed and recorded sound is very quiet. Is there any way to increase sound loudness?

Update:

When I try to convert video with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i lecture3_2013.16.09.ogv -vol 1280 lecture3_2013.16.09-loud.ogv
```

sound becomes louder, but video quality becomes poor. I can cut sound off the video and convert it:

```
ffmpeg -i lecture3_2013.16.09.ogv -vn audio.ogg
ffmpeg -i audio.ogg -vol 1280 audio-loud.ogg
```

But when I merge it back into video:

```
ffmpeg -i lecture3_2013.16.09.ogv -i audio-loud.ogg  lecture3_2013.16.09-loud.ogv
```

Quality becomes poor again :(

**SOLUTION:**

```
ffmpeg -i lecture3_2013.16.09.ogv -vn audio.ogg
ffmpeg -i audio.ogg -vol 2048 audio-loud.ogg
ffmpeg -i lecture3_2013.16.09.ogv -vcodec copy -an lecture3_2013.16.09-nosound.ogv
ffmpeg -i lecture3_2013.16.09-nosound.ogv -i audio-loud.ogg -vcodec copy lecture3_2013.16.09-loud.ogv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to increase the volume by transcoding the file with a tool like ffmpeg. ffmpeg has the `-vol` flag for that. A value of 700 may be appropriate in your case. ffmpeg also has the ability to just passthrough the video so you dont loose any quality by increasing the audio volume.

http://www.ffmpeg.org/

Comment: ffmpeg -i lecture3_2013.16.09.ogv -vol 512 -threads 4 loud-lecture3_2013.16.09.ogv

Input file is 302mb, output file is 181mb. Sound became louder, but video quality became poor. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just specify to copy the video but I see you already found that out :)